# Working with PHP Class Properties

Tags: php

I have created a new class named `Player` with 2 properties:

1. `name`
2. `ID`

I have no idea how the following code worked to me, that's why I'm asking you:

```
<?php
$player = new Player();
$player->name = "Someone";
$player->ID = 123;
$player->color = "Red"; // Why it worked?
echo $player->color; // Worked great too!
?>
```

I could set a property `color` and use it when I haven't even declared it in my class file. How is it possible?

Comment: PHP will allow you to add that property unless you explicitly tell it not to by overloading __set() and throwing an error when you do.

Comment: So, people may use empty classes just by declaring the class?

Comment: I've never had to use it, but I would guess it would be so that people can associate various data parts with a pre-defined out-the-box class, such as using the PHPMailer class to send an email and then saving to the class some sort of database id tracking, for the user whose email is just sent to, to record *in the class* who got the email sent to them. That's my guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, the feature is called [property overloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) (the "overloading" term is [misused](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#78619)! it should've been something like "interpreter hooks", instead).

> Overloading in PHP provides means to dynamically "create" properties and methods.<sup>[qoute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading)</sup>

You can use the dynamic properties as if they've been declared in the class definition; like:

```
class A {
}

$a = new A();
$a->myProperty = 'something';
```